# How can I use API 15+ in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

In Xamarin Studio, I can't use API 16, 15, 17, 19.

When I choose API 15 or higher, **OK** is disabled. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the line below the one where you select the API level it says that there is no suitable system image found.

You need to go to the Android SDK manager and install the right SDKs (including the emulator images) to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Studio go to Tool>Open Android SDK Manager and the Android SDK Manager should open. In the Android SDK Manager select the API you wish to install.